# Change a view controller's properties based on its tab bar index?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I currently have a chiclet on a viewcontroller that when pressed its supposed to navigate to a viewcontroller that is located in the tab bar.  The viewcontrollers in the tab bar are all custom view controllers.  When the chiclet is tapped I want to to navigate to a specific tab bar's selectedIndex but change a property value on that specific tab bar's viewcontroller before the switch. For example:

case .currentMap:

```
        let selectedIndex = mainTabController.selectedIndex
        let selectedController = mainTabController.selectedViewController
        if selectedController == MapViewController {// error Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UIViewController?' and 'MapViewController.Type'
            selectedController.isMapSelected = true// Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'isMapSelected'
        }
```

Any idea on how to do this property so that after clicking on chiclet the tab bar still appears at the bottom?

Comment: How about `if let selectedController = mainTabController.selectedViewController as? MapViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if let selectedController = mainTabController.selectedViewController as? MapViewController {
    selectedController.isMapSelected = true
}
```

This will grab the selected view controller, attempt to cast it as `MapViewController`, and if succesful then you can access the property.

Comment: This works, but the issues I'm is when switching the index of the tab bar controller, its showing the mapController BEFORE the .isMapSelected bool has been changed.  Is there a way to change the selectedController's property before the index change?

Comment: If you know the index of `mapController` could you grab it and update the property before navigating to its index? `let mapVC = mainTabController.viewControllers[index]`

Comment: that did it! Thanks so much!